# finding repeated sequences

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic, data-mining

I need help in finding proper algorithms to solve my goal.

Let's say I have a dataset with 10000 records about some events. I have 50 event types so each record in my dataset is assigned a number of event (from 1 to 50).

Example of my dataset (2 columns: Record number, event number):

```
1. 13
2. 24
3. 6
4. 50
5. 24
6. 6
...
10000. 46
```

As you can see in this example, I have one repetitive sequence of numbers 24, 6. Now I would like to find out how many of these and also other unknown sequences are there in my dataset. I would also like to know multiplicity of each sequence. I have checked Rabin–Karp algorithm but it seems to me, that I have to specify the pattern / sequence first. However I would like that algorithm to find it on its own.

I was told to look also on hierarchical clustering, but I am not sure if it fits my requirements.

To sum up, I would like to find algorithm that will find all repetitive sequences with their multiplicity in a dataset like above.

Comment: You can build a suffix tree and using it you can identify the repeating subsequences.

Comment: Group by event type (saving index). For each group (greater than one member) group by the event type following the first event type, and so on.

Comment: Use any of the dozen ## Sequential Frequent Pattern Mininig algorithms published. They are meant to discover patterns like this: Customers who buy product a, tend to come back the next day and buy cable b.

Comment: @SelçukCihan I have looked at suffix trees, but It seems to me, that with suffix trees I can only find known pattern in mzydatabase. However, I would like to detect all patterns/ sequences in my database without knowing about them in advance. If this can be achieved using suffix trees, can you please point me to some articles/tutorials about this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have this data in a text file with the same structure you provided,
I used the LINQ to group and count each value as shown in following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //read lines from the text file
        var arr = File.ReadAllLines("dataset.txt").AsQueryable();
        //convert the data to List<object> by convert each line to anonymous object
        var data = arr.Select(line => new { Index = line.Split('.')[0], Value = line.Split('.')[1] });
        //group the data by the value and then select the value and its count
        var res = data.GroupBy(item => item.Value).Select(group => new { Value = group.First().Value, Count = group.Count() });
        //printing result
        Console.WriteLine("Value\t\tCount");
        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}",item.Value,item.Count);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[The result of previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dezHU.png)

hope that will help you.

Comment: Looks like you just counting repeated items. For example this sequence will produce similar results: `13, 24, 6, 6, 24, 50` in your code, but it breaks OP requirement, e.g. sequence of `24 -> 6` is not repeated two times.